# How to return a value from subroutine

Tags: return-value, fortran90, subroutine

I don't want to use global value it is dangerous for a big program. Code is like this

```
subroutine has_key(id)
  if (true) then 
     return 1
  else
     return 0
  end if
end subroutine

subroutine main
   if(has_key(id))
      write(*,*) 'it works!'
end subroutine
```

how can I do something like this using subroutine. I was thinking of return a flag but I may use a global value. Anyone has idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
subroutine test(input, flag)
   integer, intent(in) :: input
   logical, intent(out) :: flag
   flag = input>=0
end subroutine
```

and

```
call test(3,myflag)
```

will set myflag to `.true.`

Note

- that subroutines return values through their argument lists;
- the use of the `intent` clause to tell the compiler what the subroutine can do with its arguments;
- my example is very simple and you will probably want to adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it with a function.  Say it returns true for even numbers

```
logical function has_key(id)
   integer, intent(in):: id
   has_key = mod(id,2) .eq. 0
end function has_key

program main
   do ii = 1, 4
      if(has_key(ii))
         print *, ii, ' has key'
      else
         print *, ii, ' no key'
      end if
   end do
end program
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!, but for some reason I have to use the subroutine cause there is no program, I try to coupling it with other programming language.